Periodic Worker Creating Thread for each interval execution
I am using periodic worker to get notify for events with user selected time interval. When i dig into log, i came to know for each interval execution worker creates and new thread.
How to Run Periodic Worker under single thread.
I have referred docs to update the enqueued work.But the result was not as expected.

can you post desired code part ?
